# What things must be kept in mind which will be later useful for me in learning HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

I am done with HTML basics currently learning CSS  , so i would like to know what i should do to explore more on this field .

Answer (score 0):

Well since I'm learning web programming now I'll help.

Style vs content - Learn to keep style separate from content. That usually means styling using external css stylesheet.

Inline vs block - Learn the difference between inline and block elements. Then you'll learn about inline-block and other kind of elements too.

Selectors - how to select the first/last child, all the descendants etc.

Specificity - how to count css specificity so you know which rule overrides which.

Learn about Grid (Container) and Flexbox.

In my opinion, the best way to learn is to open up inspector tool (ctrl + shift + c if you're using firefox) and look at how other websites are being built. Replicate them. Play around with the code and try to understand them. Build something. Once you feel comfortable with the syntax, attempt 100 Days of CSS.